# How to get HQL output in a common class

Tags: java, hibernate, list, hql

I have a common HQL for multiple classes

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select id, name from " + hibernateClass.getClass().getName());
```

`query.list();` returns a `List<Object[]>`. Now the output of the query has the same structure i.e. a `Long id` and a `String name`. So is it possible to put this content in a class, so that when I call `query.list()` everything gets copied into a list and I don't have to create a new `List` object and populate it.

Comment: You can use transformer from Guava to process result of query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410373/map-entity-using-query-in-hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410373/map-entity-using-query-in-hibernate).

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate question but just a small set of similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some possibilities which lead to a similar result (lets assume you want to have a `List<NewClass>` as result with NewClass just having the properties id and name):

1) You do `createQuery("select new NewClass(id, name) from " + hibernateClass.getClass())`

2) You create a new mapping file for NewClass for the same database table but only with the properties id and name and then your query is `createQuery("from " + NewClass.class)`

3) You just do `createQuery("from " + hibernateClass.getClass())` and you don't case about the superfluous values which where loaded. The extra amount of time for loading all columns compared to loading only the necessary columns is insignificant. If you prefer, you can nevertheless create a class or interface NewClass and for `HibernateClass extends/implements NewClass`.

Me personally I prefer 3), but that's up to your taste.

Comment: As this is duplicate it's not necessary to post responses. Between there already was an answer which could be considered as correct.

Comment: @Artem Oboturov: It is not exactly a duplicate. In the question which you cited an aggregate function is selected, so only the possibility with new() works, but here only normal properties are selected, so there are two more possibilities, 2) and 3) in my answer, which only work here.

Comment: I used the 3 option provided and it is working fine. Why is the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` needed if it could work simply in this way?