# Map query results to property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dto

Is there way to set results of a query to java DTO property using hibernate ?

Something like,

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="myDTO" table="my_table">
    <property name="myProperty" query="what_i_need" />
</class>

<query name="what_i_need">
        <![CDATA[
        from    .....
        ]]>
</query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm using spring, hibernate, java.

Comment: You may find the following useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410373/map-entity-using-query-in-hibernate

Comment: i think you need to use @Formula

Comment: Thanks blackpanther and Josef, That's what I was searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly @josef-prochazka 's suggestion of using a formula would be what you need.

See also:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column
- http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/08/03/hibernate.html?page=2
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/ColumnFormulaStringConcatenate.htm